# defining operator [ ] for both reading and writing

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

In the book of "The C++ Programming Language", the author gave the following example along with several statements:

> Defining an operator, such as [], to be used for both reading and writing is difficult where it is not acceptable simply to return a reference and let the user decide what to do with it.
>
> Cref, is to help implement a subscript operator that distinguishes between reading and writing.

Why [] is difficult to be defined when to be used for both reading and writing?
How does the definition of class Cref help to solve this issue?

```
  class String{
     struct Srep; 
     Srep *rep; 

     public: 
        class Cref;
        
     // some definitions here
     void check (int i) const { if (i<0 || rep->sz<=i) throw Range( );}
     
     char read( int i) const {return rep->s[i];}
     void write(int i, char c){ rep=rep->get_own_copy(); rep->s[i]=c;}

     Cref operator[] (int i){ check(i); return Cref(*this, i);}
     char operator[] (int i) const{check(i); return rep->s{i];}

   }

  class String::Cref{
    friend class String;
          String& s;
          int i;
          Cref(String& ss, int ii): s(ss),i(ii) {}
    public:
          operator char( ) { return s.read(i);}
          void operator=(char c){s.write(i,c);}
  };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't define a class `Cref` that solves this issue, then you have to do what `std::map` does:

```
template class <K,V> class map{
   V& operator[](K const & key);
}
```

This returns a reference, which *must* be backed by a valid memory location, and therefore

```
std::map<string,string> m;
m["foo"];
assert(m.find("foo") != m.end());
```

The assertion will succeed (meaning, `"foo"` is now a valid key in the map) even though you never assigned something to `m["foo"]`.

This counterintuitive behavior can be fixed by the `Cref` class in your example -- it can perform the appropriate logic to create `m["foo"]` only when you assign to the reference, and ensure that `m.find("foo") == m.end()` if you didn't perform some assignment when you tried to read the nonexistant `m["foo"]`.

Likewise, in your `String` class (which is a reference-counted string -- strings share their string data, and a new copy is created when you change a string whose data is shared with another string), you'd have to make a copy when using `operator[]` to read characters. The use of the `Cref` class, allows you to ensure that you only make a copy when using `operator[]` to write.

Comment: One downside to the `Cref` approach is that the new `auto` keyword for type inference, in `auto c=mystring[5]` will now have the wrong type.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s;
s[0] = 5;
```

will call `String::operator [](int)` and then `String::Cref::operator =(char)`.

However,

```
String s;
char c = s[0];
```

will call `String::operator [](int)` and then `String::Cref::operator char()`.

When reading, `String::Cref::operator char` is called, and when writing `String::Cref::operator =` is called - this allows you to distinguish between reading and writing.

Comment: Due to markdown `[](text)` doesn't display like you think it should. I generally use backticks to denote inline code fragments for disambiguation anyway (because I think it looks nice) but sometimes it's the best way to get it to display right.

Answer (score 1):

> Why [] is difficult to <strike>be defined when to be used for both</strike> *distinguish between* reading and writing?

It's because the non-const `operator[]` is called whenever you have a non-const object, even if you're using it in a read-only fashion.

Comment: It's because C++ didn't define a `[]=` operator like Ruby, a magic `update` function like Scala, or parameterized properties like Visual Basic.